# Network Timeout issue in perticular cell network in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone

The issue I am facing is regarding  request timeout error. It occurs only when device internet is switched from one carrier to another.  For instance in Kuwait if user switches from Ooredoo to Zain(https://www.kw.zain.com/kw/af/home.do), 
Or in india Airtel to Vodafone 
    - web services stop working.
**However in this situation server is stable**

Below is the log

**Logs got from the device**

```
//Logs Started Jun 28 17:09:45 My-iPhone App[964] : [967] [downlaodUpdates] 
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." 
UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x12466cc30 {Error 
Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "The request timed out." 
UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://myserver.com, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://google.com, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, 
NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}}, 
NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://myserver.com, 
NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://myserver.com, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, 
_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.}




Jun 28 17:09:45 My-iPhone networkd[92] : -[NETAWDManager 
reportStats:metricID:] AWDServerConnection newMetricContainerWithIdentifier 
failed for metric 2686983, server 0x13e523970, not reporting: { 
cellularFallbackReport = { dataUsageSnapshotsAtNetworkEvents = ( { bytesIn = 
0; bytesOut = 350; } ); "fallbackTimer_msecs" = 0; fellback = 0; 
networkEvents = ( "NETWORK_EVENT_DATA_STALL_AT_APP_LAYER" ); 
"timeToNetworkEvents_msecs" = ( 4334 ); }; clientIdentifier = 
"com.xyz.iosapp"; connectionStatisticsReport = { DNSAnswersCached = 1; 
"DNSResolvedTime_msecs" = 2; RTTvariance = 139; "appDataStallTimer_msecs" = 
3; appReportingDataStallCount = 1; "bestRTT_msecs" = 399; 
betterRouteEventCount = 0; bytesDuplicate = 0; bytesIn = 0; bytesOut = 350; 
bytesOutOfOrder = 0; bytesRetransmitted = 0; cellularFallback = 0; 
cellularRRCConnected = 0; connected = 1; connectedInterfaceType = 
"INTERFACE_TYPE_WIFI"; "connectionEstablishmentTime_msecs" = 1322; 
connectionReuseCount = 0; "currentRTT_msecs" = 396; "flowDuration_msecs" = 
54428; interfaceType = "INTERFACE_TYPE_WIFI"; kernelReportedStalls = 0; 
kernelReportingConnectionStalled = 0; kernelReportingReadStalled = 0; 
kernelReportingWriteStalled = 0; packetsDuplicate = 0; packetsIn = 0; 
packetsOut = 1; packetsOutOfOrder = 0; packetsRetransmitted = 0; 
"smoothedRTT_msecs" = 329; synRetransmissionCount = 1; tcpFastOpen = 0; 
"timeToConnectionEstablishment_msecs" = 1325; "timeToConnectionStart_msecs" 
= 3; "timeToDNSResolved_msecs" = 2; "timeToDNSStart_msecs" = 0; trafficClass 
= 0; }; delegated = 0; reportReason = 
"REPORT_REASON_DATA_STALL_AT_APP_LAYER"; }
```

Comment: When you switch networks you are going to get a new IP address and timeouts may occur. Networks are unreliable. You should handle the error and retry/reconnect

Comment: @Paulw11 After changing network ,i am opening app

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario; restart your application, i think it will fixed your issue.